# How can I run a script or app as sudo with a click?

Tags: mac, sudo

I have a certain program that doesn't work right unless I run it as sudo.  I don't mind having to type in my password, but I'd like to get out of the whole process of opening command line and typing "sudo ./"+script name.  If you create a script that runs as sudo and click it, it just fails due to permissions.  Is there a way to do this more quickly?

Comment: I would caution you from disabling the sudo system wide, it is there to protect you. Try adding the password in your script.

Comment: I don't know how to add passwords to a script.  My question isn't about disabling sudo system wide.

Comment: add this to your script (do shell script "whatever" user name "username" password "password" with administrator privileges) replacing the "" with your stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Run `sudo visudo` (or `EDITOR=nano sudo visudo`) and add a line like this:

```
%admin ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/myscript
```

Then create a `.command` file that runs `/usr/bin/myscript`:

```
echo sudo myscript>~/Desktop/test.command
chmod +x ~/Desktop/test.command
echo $'#!/bin/sh\nls /var/root'|sudo tee /usr/bin/myscript;sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/myscript
```

Or if for example you want to run `sudo purge` without having to enter a password, add

```
 %admin ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/purge
```

to sudoers.

Comment: Is there a way to make a script ask for `sudo` password (Prompt the password Dialog Box)?